# Cant run index.jsp from web aplication

Tags: java, jsp

I made Java Enterprise app using Java 15.0.2 and GlassFish 4.1.1.

This is what I got in glassfish output:

```
`C:\Users\s\Documents\Java\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
C:\Users\s\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath C:\Users\s\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1367306742.jar com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 64094 com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish31Agent
[2021-03-19 09:07:21,872] Artifact demo:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
`
```

Unable to ping server at localhost 4848

Comment: That is notificaton from Intelij. Im running localhost at 8080 
Also I got this notification: 9:18 PM It is possible to bind and connect to localhost:8080 at the same time - application server will probably compete with some other software on the port

Answer (score 0):

Use the ping-connection-pool subcommand in remote mode to test if a connection pool is usable. For example, if you create a new JDBC connection pool for an application that is expected to be deployed later, you can test the JDBC pool with this subcommand before the application is deployed. Running a ping will force the creation of the pool if it hasn't already been created.
Before You Begin
According to Oracle Glassfish admin guide

Before you can contact a connection pool, the connection pool must be created with authentication, and the server or database must be running.

```
Ensure that the server is running.

Remote subcommands require a running server.

Ping a connection pool by using the ping-connection-pool(1) subcommand.
```